# Draw Spectrogram STFT in C#, what function can I use?

Tags: c#, fft, spectrogram

Assume that I have STFT (short time fourier transform) data, how would these can be displayed on the picture box as spectrogram of frequency vs time, what function in C# can I use ?

Comment: There isn't a built in function for the .NET framework for calculating STFT or displaying specrograms.  This may be two questions? Are you asking what library you could use to find the STFT of an audio file, then how would you write a spectrogram user control?

Comment: Hi Matt, I just need to know the second question, I can use Naudio library to get STFT, what I mean is once I got the frequency data vs time, how would I display it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WPF Sound Visualization Library isn't bad for this type of thing, although it doesn't have a spectrograph control.

- [WPF Sound Visualization Library](http://inchoatethoughts.com/wpf-sound-visualization-library)
- [Codeplex project with source](http://wpfsvl.codeplex.com/)

While not a .NET implementation Audacity is open source.  So you may be able to poke around in there and see how they created their Spectrograph control

- [Audacity Source](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/source)

There is also some Matlab code here that should allow you to get to where you need

- [Matlab code Stanford.edu](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/st/Spectrogram_Speech.html)